# How to type from keyboard on screen in Allegro?

Tags: c++, string, types, key, allegro

I want to set name of character in my Allegro game, so need to save it to string and show it on the screen. Is there better way than comparing event keycodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.2.1.1/events.html#allegro_event_key_char). Listen for these events and use the `keyboard.unichar` field to get the character pressed.

Not that unlike `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN`, `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR` will fire repeatedly when the key is held (depending on the user's keyboard repeat setting). If this is undesireable, ignore events with `repeat=true`.

Comment: Everything is beautiful. how do we convert **unichar** to utf-8 characters?

It is very difficult to code this manually. For someone living in the UAE, KEY_A could be the **letter elif**.